# CSS Font property syntax, specifying size with no px or unit

Tags: css

I am used to seeing this, `font: 16px/40px`, however, I just opened up some code that has this syntax, `font: 16px/1.5`, what does this mean?

Comment: It would be nice if the person who downvoted me, explained why they downvoted me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shorthand for font size of 16px and a line height of 1.5